# apt-get remove php5 without installing apache2

Tags: apt, apache-httpd, php5

How can I uninstall/purge `php5` without reinstalling `apache2`?

I have removed `apache2` and now I want to remove `php5`, but the system wants me to reinstall `apache2` to uninstall `php5`. Why?

```
# aptitude why php5
BB  phpmyadmin Depends libapache2-mod-php5 | libapache2-mod-php5filter | php5-cgi | php5-fpm | php5
```

Comment: Debian is becoming an unjustified dependency hell - I have had similar problems with several packages, and this behaviour does not make sense

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `phpmyadmin` installed (albeit in a broken state), which is why whichever tool you’re using want to install `apache2` when you try to remove `php5`. (Although I’d actually expect most tools to want to remove `phpmyadmin` instead.)

To remove `php5` without installing anything else, you need to also remove `phpmyadmin`.